# Return value of UploadStringAsync().?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, return, webclient

My question is correct or incorrect I don't know, but I would like to know if is it possible to return the value of UploadStringAsync() of post methods using WebClient?

```
    string serviceURL = REST_URI + servicePath;
    Uri URI = new Uri(serviceURL);
    System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
    webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += this.sendPostCompleted;
    webClient.UploadStringAsync(URI, HTTP_POST, result);
    return ??;
```

If we can return the value of `UploadStringAsync(URI, HTTP_POST, result);` please let me know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`UploadStringCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstringcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and get result in event handler. Once upload completes (failed or succeed) event is raised.

Attach

```
client.UploadStringCompleted 
               += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler (UploadStringCallback2);
```

Use:

```
void UploadStringCallback2(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//e.Result use it
}
```

If you want to return result of the upload you can wait for event to be raised like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820911/1714342)
 using `AutoResetEvent`

Comment: i got the results.. i need to extract particular data example:id from the list of results..

Answer (score 4):

From .NET 4.5 we can use `UploadStringTaskAsync` to retrieve return value directly.

```
string rspBody = await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, "POST");
```

ref: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstringtaskasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_UploadStringTaskAsync_System_String_System_String_)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to return from that function. You've already set up an event handler for `UploadStringCompleted`, you can get the result of the action in the handler.

This is the signature:

```
public delegate void UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e
)
```

The second parameter has the information you need: [UploadStringCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.uploadstringcompletedeventargs.aspx), the `Result` property contains the server's response.

Comment: i got the results.. i need to extract particular data example:id from the list of results..