# Return value after UploadStringCompleted event raised?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, return, webclient

I able to upload data from client side, and got the response. My question is how to return a value from LoginRequest method after UploadStringCompleted event was completed.
Or How to return a value from UploadStringCompleted event. Please See my code below.
But When I am doing return "true" line is executed before webClientLogin_UploadStringCompleted method called.
Below link have something similar but I didn't get answer for my question
Click [here] ([Return value of UploadStringAsync().?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374582/return-value-of-uploadstringasync))
Thanks in Advance.

```
public string LoginRequest(string token)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var result= serializer.Serialize(token);
    client .Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
    client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClientLogin_UploadStringCompleted);
    client.UploadStringAsync(URI, HTTP_POST, result);
    return "true";
}

private void webClientLogin_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var validate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(e.Result);  
}
```

Shall I do anything with AutoResetEvent or ManualReSetEvent?

Answer (score 1):

You should not return anything from the LoginRequest method. Instead do the things that you want to do from the webClientLogin_UploadStringCompleted event. because it will get called when the upload is completed.

Comment: Can you state How to? Because UploadStringCompleted delegate's return type was void bydefault.

Comment: depends upon where are you using that "true".

Comment: we cant change the return type of the delegate. whatever do when the Login request returns true. try to do that from within the uploadstringcompleted delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UploadStringTaskAsync` which returns a `Task<string>` allowing you to use `async`/`await`. Try this:

```
public async Task<string> LoginRequest(string token)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var result = serializer.Serialize(token);

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
    var response = await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(URI, HTTP_POST, result);
    // do something with the response here, eg. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject();

    return "true";
}
```

Also, why return `true` as a string? Use a boolean if you can.

Comment: For the question being I use return true but actually I am working in asp.net mvc and I am using this connectivity in another class file, So I have to call the method form action and return the value back to my action in controller.

Comment: When I try above I have an error states WebClient does not contain the definition for UploadStringTaskAsync.And cannot find all the types required by async modifier.