# how to await till UploadStringAsync method completes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

I am trying/wanting to wait till async task completes here is what i am trying to do

```
public class savetodbsingle 
{
    public static  string  insert(string id, string type, string cat)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://yxz.com");

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", json);

        wc.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadComplete6;
    }

    private static   void wc_UploadComplete6(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Saving to database logic here 
    }
}
```

and calling the method from other page

```
//calling method
savetodbsingle.insert(id,type,cat)); 

// i want to show messegebox from here when above task completes 
MessegeBox.Show("Completed");
```

So how to achieve this? I had tried to make method async and then await it but that did not help

Comment: Do you have access to [`UploadStringTaskAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138531(v=vs.110).aspx) in windows phone? If not, do you have access to the class [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: no i dont have access to it , and i dont know about Taskcompletionsource  @ScottChamberlain

Comment: it gives error cannot await void @Eldho

Comment: @SD7 I'm sorry , please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20374676/1876572

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instead the UploadStringTaskAsync Method

This will return a task which you can await.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
 public static  async string  insert(string id, string type, string cat, Action<object,Exception> callback)
    {
         ----
        string result  = await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, "POST", json);

    }
```

Comment: your code is not exactly the solution, but i have used UploadStringTaskAsync as said and achieved the same

Comment: check my answer @Igoy

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if [`WebClient.UploadStringTaskAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstringtaskasync) comes with [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) for Windows Phone 8, but in case someone is wondering how it is implemented and how to use [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd449174), here it is its implementation, taken from [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,3cf3fcc75901d188,references):

```
[HostProtection(ExternalThreading = true)]
[ComVisible(false)]
public Task<string> UploadStringTaskAsync(Uri address, string method, string data)
{
    // Create the task to be returned
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(address);

    // Setup the callback event handler
    UploadStringCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (sender, e) => HandleCompletion(tcs, e, (args) => args.Result, handler, (webClient, completion) => webClient.UploadStringCompleted -= completion);
    this.UploadStringCompleted += handler;

    // Start the async operation.
    try { this.UploadStringAsync(address, method, data, tcs); }
    catch
    {
        this.UploadStringCompleted -= handler;
        throw;
    }

    // Return the task that represents the async operation
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a callback. How you define the callback is up to you. As an example I defined it as an Action taking two parameters: an object that can be used to give something back to the caller and an exception in case something went wrong during saving.

```
public class savetodbsingle 
{
    private Action<object, Exception> _callback;

    public static  string  insert(string id, string type, string cat, Action<object,Exception> callback)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://yxz.com");

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadComplete6;

        _callback = callback;

        wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", json);

    }

    private static void wc_UploadComplete6(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Saving to database logic here 

        // When done, you can return something if needed
        // or return an exception when something bad happened.
        _callback(someObject, someException)
    }
}
```

and calling the method from other page

```
//calling method
savetodbsingle.insert(id,type,cat, handleSaved)); 

private void handleSaved(object o, Exception e)
{
    MessegeBox.Show("Completed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution how i achieved it

```
 public static async  Task  insert(string id, string type, string cat)
            {
       WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";


           var responce=     await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, "POST", json);
             jsons = responce.ToString().Trim();

             saving();//save to database logic here
    }
```

and  calling method like this

```
 await savetodbsingle.insert(id, type, cat);
 Messegebox.Show("Completed");
```