# Return value after timer finishes

Tags: c#, timer

I have a simple application that connects to API, scans a file and checks its status. Scanning can take a period of time, and I want to 'ask' api every 5 seconds about the file status, and, if it's clean - return true, if other - return false.
The problem is that I don't know how to tell the program to wait until the condition have been met before returning value. My code looks something like this:

```
bool Scan(string filePath){
    Scanner.Scan(filePath);
    //now repeat line below every 2s until the result is positive
    var result = Scanner.CheckStatus();
    // I dont want to go below before status is positive or x seconds has elapsed
    return result
}
```

Comment: Well the code you have will run Scanner.Scan and on completion run result=scanner.checkstatus, so, you need to look into either threads or tasks to move the call for the scan out, and then montior the process

Comment: I tried using timer, and it ran CheckStatus every 2 s but this code here still went on and returned result before CheckStatus could finish

Comment: Is there a `StatusChanged` event in your `Scanner`? If not you could implement it. Then you could use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2820911/284240).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async/await` approach looks clear enough. You can use `async/await` even you didn't have UI.

```
async Task<bool> Scan(string filePath)
{
    Scanner.Scan(filePath);
    var result = Scanner.CheckStatus();

    while(result == false)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        result = Scanner.CheckStatus();
    }

    return result
}
```

Because your `Scanner.Scan` method working with IO - it become very good candidate for asynchronous method which uses `async/await`.

Comment: It looks very clean! I'm going to try it too. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I am accepting this answer, it works like a charm and I don't have to use any timers. Async/Await rocks! Edit: just for the note, i had to use "await" on Scanner.CheckStatus() (It's async), cause without await it hanged.

Comment: @Kuker, if `Scanner.CheckStatus` is asynchronous method the I suggest to rename it by adding suffix "Async".

Answer (score 3):

**Threads**

Below example will put down to sleep Your thread. This means You are unable to do anything else during that time, if Your application is single threated.

Code that sleep the thread is:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //time in ms, 1 sec
```

*Comment by @EpicSam:* This will make your program unresponsive during the sleep. In case you have some sort of user interface that needs to be responsive, consider using line below instead:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

In example, it should looks like:

```
bool Scan(string filePath){
    Scanner.Scan(filePath);
    var result = Scanner.CheckStatus();
    while(result != ResultType.Positive)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //time in ms
        result = Scanner.CheckStatus();
    }
    return result
}
```

Simplified:

```
bool Scan(string filePath){
    Scanner.Scan(filePath);
    ResultType result;

    while((result = Scanner.CheckStatus()) != ResultType.Positive)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //time in ms

    return result
}
```

**Timers & events**

Another way to handle the case is use `Timers` and `Evenets`. You will set up timer, it will do the work each time You want. Once it find the result is done, it will send message to You. **This is the correct way**, however putting `Thread` to `Sleep` also works.

Check [Comparing Timer with DispatcherTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111645/comparing-timer-with-dispatchertimer) to choose which Timer to use.

- *Please note that the code below make different results then for Threads -> it does run the whole Scan method in loop. Which includes running the `Scanner.Scan()` method*

-

```
using System.Timers;

public class MyClass
{
    Timer mTimer;
    string mFilePath;

    public delegate void StatusCheck(bool value);
    public event StatusCheck StatusChecked; 

    MyClass(string filePath)
    {
        mFilePath = filePath;

        mTimer = new Timer(); //time in ms
        mTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Scan);
    }

    public void Start()
    { mTimer.Enabled=true; }

    private void Scan(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)    
    {
        Scanner.Scan(filePath);
        ResultType result;
        if(result = Scanner.CheckStatus())
        {
            this.StatusChecked?.Invoke(result); 
        }
    }

}
```

Usage will look like:

```
//some code ...
MyClass checker = new MyClass("C:\a.txt");
checker.StatusChecked += new StatusCheck(myVoid);
checker.Start();

//some more code ..

private void myVoid(bool result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("My result is: " + result );
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I'm going to try to implement it.

Comment: This will make your program unresponsive during the sleep. In case you have some sort of user interface that needs to be responsive, consider using `await Task.Delay(5000)` instead.

Comment: `await Task.Delay` will be much cleaner solution even without UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Scan(string filePath)
{
    var timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
    Scanner.Scan(filePath);
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    do 
    {
        result = Scanner.CheckStatus();
        if(result) return true;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

    } while(stopwatch.Elapsed < timeout)

    return false;
}
```

note it is a simple but naive implementation as it does not prevent the CheckStatus() call itself to exceed the 5 seconds timeout.